# Creating Sharepoint Alerts only for published documents

Tags: alert

I'm attempting to create an alert via code such that it triggers only when a document is published.  I have used the following with no success.

SPAlert

```
alert = currUser.Alerts.Add();
alert.Filter ="<Query><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"vti_level\"/><Value type=\"integer\">1</Value></Eq></Query>"; 
alert.Title = "Test Alert '" + selectedFileName + "'" ; 
alert.AlertType = SPAlertType.Item; 
alert.EventType = SPEventType.All; 
alert.Item = selectedFileListItem;
alert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate; 
alert.AlwaysNotify = true;  
alert.Update(true);
```

Comment: Betty, you're not going to be able to setup an alert to fire when a document is specifically published.  You could setup an alert to fire on modify, which should pick-up the publishing action, but it will pick-up any action that modifies the document.

Comment: You wouldn't want the scope of the alert to be a specific item, you'd want to target a list...so alert.List (or alert.ListId) instead of alert.Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rob I was able to solve this problem.  The following worked for me.

```
            SPAlert alert = sourceWebObj.CurrentUser.Alerts.Add(); 
            alert.Filter = "<Query><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"_Level\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Query>";
            alert.Title = selectedFileName + " - Publish Alert";                 
            alert.AlertType = SPAlertType.Item;      
            alert.EventType = SPEventType.Modify;                
            alert.Item = selectedFileListItem;
            alert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate; 
            alert.AlwaysNotify = true; 
            alert.Update();
```

Comment: I tried exact code it doent seem to work, will this work only for Item or List as well .

Answer (score 4):

Betty, try something like this (...it works for me):

```
            SPAlert alert = site.RootWeb.CurrentUser.Alerts.Add();
            alert.Filter = "<Query><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"_Level\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Query>";
            alert.Title = "Test Publishing Alert";
            alert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
            alert.EventType = SPEventType.Modify;
            alert.List = site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Site Pages");
            alert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
            alert.AlwaysNotify = true;
            alert.Update();
```

Note that I'm using **_Level** instead of **vti_level**, **alert.List** instead of **alert.Item**, and **SPEventType.Modify** instead of **SPEventType.All**.  You also have **Value type="integer"** in your query, s/b Value Type="Integer" ...**integer** is probably OK, but **type** definitely won't work.

Comment: Rob, thank you for your help.  Would your code fire for ANY file that is published in this list?  I specifically need it to fire for each specific file.

Comment: Yes...it would work for any file. Just as a FYI, you should mark my answer as correct in lieu of creating your own answer and marking it correct...I don't get any credit for answering your question when you do that.